# Are we now allowing "shopping questions"?

Tags: discussion

Are we now allowing "shopping questions"?

I'm just checking because I didn't see a single vote to close on [Looking for red letter bible in database format](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32128/looking-for-red-letter-bible-in-database-format)

Generally, on StackExchange sites ["Shopping questions" seem to be discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and [this older post from this Meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/are-book-recomendations-considered-on-topic/199#199) seems to indicate that they are off-topic or at least discouraged here.

This question is clearly asking us to recommend a resource, and seems like a no-brainer for an automatic, swift closure here. It's really a software shopping question, and not even about Christianity at all, jut asking for a resource to make Bible software with the red letters marked in the data source.

What gives?  It gets upvotes and no votes to close? Are we allowing shopping questions now?

Comment: Upon further consideration, I have come to the conclusion that the other question is *not* a duplicate. These questions are asking about fundamentally different types of questions. This question asks about shopping questions--the other asks about "Identify this" questions. They are treated differently on different stacks. Movies.SE, for instance, permits "identify this" while prohibiting shopping questions. There's no reason we should inherently treat them the same, either.

Answer (score 6):

Well, yeah, we are allowing them now. Recently *you* advocated that we do allow it and got 11 ups and no downs.

[Should we accept "Help me find this thing" questions, or "identify this" questions?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/should-we-accept-help-me-find-this-thing-questions)

I don't really know where to go here except that there is now a very obvious conflict between actions and policy.

Comment: Oh, cobblestones!  You're right.  I guess I don't know why I thought of one as a "shopping question"and not the other.

Comment: So now I'm wondering if my question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidStratton Haha. I guess so. Ironic how I asked last time then you answered, now you asked this time and I answered.