# Why does the verse-identification tag still exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

[We're pretty settled on removing it](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4200/3961), I think.

So how do we go about doing that?

Comment: But now there are lots of questions which are badly tagged with 'bible'! I think it would be better for the tag to exist, even if every question with it is closed.

Comment: @curiousdannii New questions will not have the tag though. Further, most of the question that did have the tag are closed or I submitted a close vote. They'll be deleted eventually. I suppose I could have made a new tag "off-topic". No other tags seemed relevant.

Comment: most have positive votes so they won't be deleted. I was able to think of other tags for all but one.

Comment: @curiousdannii The community can still make delete votes on them. Takes 10K rep though. I'm not sure how often that really happens. You're a better tagger than I am ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse-identification and systematically edit the tags out of the posts.

The tag exists as long as there is at least one question that has the tag.  [Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Comment: Oh, there's only eight. Okay. On my way to some fancy editing. Sorry active page, you're about to be bumped.

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch - don't be afraid to vote to close any that are off-topic while you're editing, and point back to http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/wheres-the-line-with-the-verse-identification-tag/4200#4200 in the comments

Comment: Right, govner. .

Comment: And no more tag come about 3AM. I think that's like 7 hours from now.

Comment: I think it's gone. Doesn't show up in search.

Comment: This meta post will self destruct in three seconds ...