# Why is there a truth tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, truth-questions

Related: [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth)

The site tour specifically states, "Do not ask about truth questions..."

Why is there a [truth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/truth) tag if truth questions are discouraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer. There should not be.

There <strike>are</strike> were only ten questions with that tag, and tags that are unused are deleted every day. The answer here is to edit the tag off of the questions that contain it, then wait a day. The tag will then be deleted. Also, whoever happens to be removing the tag should make a close vote too if the question happens to be off-topic by today's guidelines.

This came up similarly with the [verse-identification](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verse-identification) tag: [Why does the verse-identification tag still exist?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4316/why-does-the-verse-identification-tag-still-exist)

I'm going to begin editing out the tags. You are welcome to join me. With only ten questions it won't take long.

Comment: I removed a couple, I'll let you decide what to do with the questions that *only* have the truth tag.

Comment: @ShemSeger There're all gone now. [tag:truth]

Comment: @ShemSeger I had a legitimate concern with three of them: [Should these question have a truth tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4329) Worst case scenario is that the community wants the tag and we add it back on to those three questions.

Comment: I thought the tag was sometimes used for questions about truth as a phenomenon, in which case it would be appropriate. But I can't think of a question like that now...

Comment: @curiousdannii Hence my questions about those three. Of the ten, only those three even seemed on-topic.

Comment: @fredsbend once they were detagged I couldn't see the old questions, though now I've seen the other meta question.

Comment: @curiousdannii There should be a big old block of questions edited by us all within a few minutes starting about a minute after this answer was posted.

Comment: Tag master, @curiousdannii. There are now 16 questions tagged truth. I would close at least half of them. Some *do* contain usage of truth as a phenomenon.

Answer (score 7):

I respectfully disagree with Fredsbend.

There is a massive difference between what this community regards as 'a truth question' and an on-topic question regarding a denominational or doctrinal perspective on 'truth'. In my view, it is entirely legitimate to have the 'truth' tag for the purpose of the latter.

Examples:

- [What is the biblical support that the Catholic Church is the custodian of truth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34280/what-is-the-biblical-support-that-the-catholic-church-is-the-custodian-of-truth)
- [What is the basis for the LDS belief that religious truth is confirmed by what you feel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35577/what-is-the-basis-for-the-lds-belief-that-religious-truth-is-confirmed-by-what-y)
- [Why are some denominations so against the idea of personal revelation as a source of Truth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/13746/why-are-some-denominations-so-against-the-idea-of-personal-revelation-as-a-sourc)
- [What is the Biblical basis that prayer is sufficient as a way to recognize truth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34835/what-is-the-biblical-basis-that-prayer-is-sufficient-as-a-way-to-recognize-truth)

Comment: I agree and have upvoted. But the damage has been done. Actually, only three questions out of the ten were even on-topic in the first place. We'll work out what the truth tag should be used for, create it, then add it to those three questions.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining what sort of question would be legitimately tagged with a 'truth' tag. Can you offer an example?

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, I've included some examples.

Comment: I've created and added the truth tag to those questions. And also a few others.