# Should these question have a truth tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, retagging, completed

[The truth tag was recently removed by me and another user](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4327/3961). For the most part, it was used on Truth questions and the tag's existence seems to imply that Truth questions are allowed.

However, in doing so, I came across a few questions that seems like they could have a legitimate use for the tag:

1. [What does it mean to "worship in truth"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/what-does-it-mean-to-worship-in-truth)
2. [What is the Biblical basis that prayer is sufficient as a way to recognize truth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34835/what-is-the-biblical-basis-that-prayer-is-sufficient-as-a-way-to-recognize-truth)
3. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36020/why-does-jesus-say-very-truly-i-tell-you

The first one admittedly seems like it's primarily opinion based, but I'm not sure, so I've not made a close vote.

The other two are certainly on topic. The second without a doubt. Some might object to the third, but it looks like they just would like an explanation on why a particular phrase is continually stressed in the work, so it might be better on Hermeneutics.

The question in this meta post is that they all seem like they could have a legitimate use of a [truth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/truth) tag. Should we have such a tag despite the pretty much guaranteed misuse of it? If so, what should it be used for and what should the excerpt say?

---

**Update:**

I have since created the [truth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/truth) tag with an excerpt almost exactly like the example in bruised reed's answer below. I have added it to questions that appropriately needed it. Most are listed [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4330/3961).

Comment: Maybe the tag could be along the lines of "Truth as a phenomenon"

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are off-topic (as I agree that 1. is) then the question is pretty irrelevant, but in the case where the question is on-topic and it does have a legitimate focus on 'truth' then I believe tagging it as such should be quite legitimate.  It should be fairly clear that 'a truth question' is not determined by a tag or even a reference to 'truth' in it, but whether the primary purpose of the question is to determine what is actually true, rather than what a defineable perspective believes about truth.

Suggested text for tag description:

> For questions about *beliefs* regarding truth (note: questions about what is actually true have been judged to be off-topic - see Meta post: "We can't handle the truth").

Comment: So what should the excerpt say? How will that help prevent the misuse of the tag?

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch Perhaps: 'For questions about beliefs regarding the nature of truth (note: questions about what is actually true have been judged to be off-topic - see Meta post: "We can't handle the truth")' The last could be linked if the tag excerpt can handle doing that.

Comment: I think if you click through to the tag wiki, it is clickable, but the popup is not. At least, I've never seen it. I think that's a good excerpt. It's not too philosophical? The "nature of truth" seems to be an inherent philosophical question, not necessarily a religious or Christian one. I think I'm just having trouble seeing a 'type' of question that would use this tag.

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch good point - "the nature of" is unnecessary and can be removed. Perhaps "beliefs" should be italicized for emphasis if that's possible.

Comment: Yes, I think that is much better. Perhaps add it to your answer.