# Why is my question bad? It got at least 1 downvote and has no answers or comments

Tags: discussion, scope, downvoting

It's a question on leprosy: [What did Jesus do regarding the Jews believing that some diseases were sometimes due to sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/what-did-jesus-do-regarding-the-jews-believing-that-some-diseases-were-sometimes)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the problem is that your question is just too broad and opinion-based, and more of a discussion-starter (which isn't what this site is about) than a question that calls for a specific, objective answer (which *is* what this site is about).

See these help articles:

1. [How we are different than other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)
2. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
3. [How do I ask a good question?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

To make your question work here, you would either have to ask for the perspective of a specific denomination, such as Roman Catholics or Lutherans, on the question, or you would need to ask for the Biblical basis for a particular viewpoint on the question.

I would also suggest making the question more specific, with less discussion-like speculation. Think about what, *exactly,* you want to know, and specify which denominational viewpoint you want on that question. If you do that, your question will fare better here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What is the opinion-based here? I was asking about Jesus' reaction to false beliefs.

Comment: Did you read the help articles I linked for you above?

Comment: I read them before. I'm not new to stackexchange or christianity stackexchange. I'm just using a different account

Comment: I don't have much to add to what I said above. The question meanders around, with much discussion-like speculation, and is rather non-specific. After reading it over several times, I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: People thought something wrong at the time. So what did Jesus say or do in response to such wrong thinking? My question was answered

Answer (score 2):

Your last (somewhat tangential) paragraph in particular isn't a good fit here: questioning *why* Jesus didn't do some things is off-topic.

The rest of the question is actually a verse search question, which are generally not considered acceptable here ([see here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4199/21576)).  The answer is either "no such verse exists," or perhaps something like the answer I've provided.

Comment: I did not ask that. I was stating what I was feeling to provide context for why I asked what I asked. So this is a bad question? http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44162/looking-for-a-passage-in-the-old-testament

Comment: @RedRackham That's helpful to know.  If you edit the question to make that a bit more clear, that would make it a better question.  As for your link, yes, to me that's definitely within the common definition of a verse search question.  I personally don't have much of an issue with this type of verse search question, so I won't vote to close, but others very well may.

Comment: What do you mean type?

Comment: @RedRackham Personally I think only "easy" verse search questions should be closed (like "Where in the Bible was the earth created?"), since answers can easily be found elsewhere on the internet.  This one is more complex, and thus I don't feel a strong need to close it.  But, like I said, others will disagree with me.

Comment: Oh okay thanks!

Comment: @RedRackham I've provided an answer expressing this opinion on a different question, so that we can get a better idea of the community's opinion on this issue: [Where's the boundary line with the “verse-identification” tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5774/21576)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question should more be on the lines of:

> Can sickness come from sin? What did Jesus say concerning this?

You seem to be asking a question already holding to an answer, that sickness coming from sin was merely Jewish superstition. Personally, I think there can be sin unto sickness, just as there is sin unto death.

1 John 5:16  If anyone sees his brother sinning a sin not unto death, he shall ask and he will give life to him, to those sinning not unto death. **There is a sin unto death**; I do not say that he should make request concerning that.

Also consider Miriam's rebellion resulting in her leprosy:

Numbers 12:10  And when the cloud had departed from over the tent; **there Miriam was, leprous**, as white as snow. And Aaron turned toward Miriam, and there she was, leprous. (11)  And Aaron said to Moses, Oh, my lord, please do not lay **this sin upon us that we have so foolishly committed**.

Comment: Asking "Can sickness come from sin?" would be a truth question and thus off-topic.

Comment: Point taken. I guess something more like "Biblical basis for and against sickness coming from sin"