# Why are verse-identification questions not migrated to BH.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

Should we migrate this `verse-identification` [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/97792/10672) (and future ones) to Biblical Hermeneutics site, or are there cases where they should remain here?

Comment: I am not aware that SE-BH do verse searches either. Surely folk can search using a concordance for themselves ? Or just Google ?

Answer (score 2):

Verse identification questions are off-topic on BH.SE.

Honestly they almost never make for good questions. In my opinion it's not a type of question that SE sites should cater for.

But for now they are permitted here, although the mods will be quite strict on them. The [criteria I use](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5819/6071) is

> I would like to propose that for these questions to be acceptable the question must specify the *exact* wording searched for (and preferably give several alternatives they tried), as well as tell us what passages those searches suggested and why they are wrong. Without telling us those passages all these questions will do is duplicate the work of a search engine.

Comment: Are you putting that out there as a proposal that we close all verse identification questions or just stating your opinion? I've always tried to abide by https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/wheres-the-boundary-line-with-the-verse-identification-tag/5774#5774 which makes the question at hand on topic.

Comment: @PeterTurner Well no, I would still moderate by the criteria [I posted to that question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5819/6071). But even questions that meet those criteria aren't very *good* questions, IMO. If the rest of the community wanted to see them gone, then I'd be happy to ban them.